# Where should I put the initial table schema scripts for aurora postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, aws-cloudformation, amazon-aurora

I am using aurora postgresql on AWS and I have put all infrastructure code in cloudformation including cluster and db instance. Next I am going to put table creation sql script and I wonder where I should put it? Can I put the script somewhere in the infrastructure code? Does cloudformation support that?

All my application code(typescript) is running inside lambda so there is not much framework I am using. How should I manage the datable table schema?

Answer (score 0):

Cloudformation is good at creating "resources", like your lambdas, database clusters etc.  It's not designed to keep things like database schema tables up-to-date (i.e. created as in your question, but also consider what you need to do if your database structure needs to be updated).

You could create a custom resource (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) that did not create an actual resource, but instead created your table schema, but I don't think that would be a good way to solve your problem (if you try this make sure your custom resource depends on your database resources so that things are created and updated in the required order).

I think a better plan would be to use a tool designed to keep database schemas up-to-date (such as https://www.liquibase.org/) and have an AWS CodePipeline that creates/updates your CloudFormation stack, and then runs liquibase up keep the database schema up-to-date.  You'll be faced with the choice of either leaning how to write custom resources and use them in a way they were not intended for, or learning codepipeline and ending up with a CD pipeline for your app as well as solving the database schema problem.